# ExtJS Counting Selected Sencha Boxes

Tags: jquery, extjs, sencha-cmd

I need to count how many list items are selected here

[image]

Now each line is made up of a Table html item `<table>` that gets to have "x-grid-item-selected" class if I select, and if I unselect, it doesn't have this. So I am trying to count how many selected boxes in this list, so all I need to count is how many of this class is there.

When I pull up the console and type in `$('.x-grid-item-selected').length;` I get undefined error. Even when I enter `$('div').length` I get an undefined error. What is the best way I can count and increase/decrease how many of these boxes are selected?

So basically, I want to count selected ones and display on the page saying "2 selected", I can run `$('div').length` generally anywhere but even `$('div').length` fails to run on this page saying undefined.

```
<table id="..." class="x-grid-item x-grid-item-selected"></table>
<table id="..." class="x-grid-item x-grid-item-selected"></table>
<table id="..." class="x-grid-item"></table>
<table id="..." class="x-grid-item"></table>
<table id="..." class="x-grid-item"></table>
<table id="..." class="x-grid-item"></table>
```

Comment: Can you please share some code? It will be easy to track the issue.

Comment: Sure, thank you I am sharing now.

Comment: why would you want to use `jQuery` on an `ExtJS` grid and what this has to do with `SenchaCmd`?

Comment: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.selection.Model.html#method-getSelected ...would be an easy way to do that.

Comment: I am using Sencha CMD to run the application. I need to count how many entries in the list are selected, and don't know if ExtJS has a way of doing it that's already implemented so, I am seeking to do it in jQuery

Comment: @Peace see the above comment ...no need for jQuery; better learn the framework. `SenchaCmd` is nevertheless not really related to this question; that's alike all the `Android Studio` tags, which I remove on a daily basis. it reads `For questions related to Sencha's command tool.` (most tags hint for what they should be used for)

Comment: grid.getSelectionModel().getCount() seems like it'll do it but no idea where it's suppose to be and how can I update as user selects or unselects divs on the page.

Comment: @Peace cannot tell either, based upon some HTML. most likely that code would need to run when a checkbox is being checked or unchecked; so that the count would be updated when clicking it.

Comment: You could use `grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection().length` to get the selected record length and to get all the selected item `grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()`. here is [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/26ea)

Comment: found the event: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.selection.Model.html#method-onSelectChange

Comment: @Jadhav I see the list on that Fiddle but no counter...

Comment: listeners: {
                select: function () {
                    $('#countCheckboxes').innerHTML++;
                },
                deselect: function () {
                    $('#countCheckboxes').innerHTML--;
                }
            }

Comment: This code does the job of increasing or decreasing but since it's jQuery it won't run inside listener item. That's the only problem...

Comment: solved it......

Comment: @Peace In comment I have mentioned what you need to use `grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection().length` this will return the count of selected items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the answer

```
listeners: {
            select: function () {
                document.getElementById('countCheckboxes').innerHTML++;
            },
            deselect: function () {
                document.getElementById('countCheckboxes').innerHTML--;
            }
        }
```

and

```
html: '<span id="countCheckboxes">0</span> Selected'
```

Comment: this doesn't consider pre-selected check-boxes; combine that with Narendra's suggestion and it would also work, when check-boxes were already selected, on load... directly accessing the DOM is ordinary not the optimum; while the DOM could be accessed with `Ext.get('countCheckboxes')`.

Comment: I don't think, this is right way to do this. If you are usng the ExtJS then you need to use all the available method. Pelase refer the [ExtJS docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#method-getSelection) for more details.

Comment: Zeitler, There isn't any pre-selected lined on my end. @Jadhav, If it's short and easy fix like this, why bother doing longer lines of coding and trying to figure it out??.. for me this trick did what I needed it to do perfectly so, no need to invest hours into figuring out how to do it using ExtJS functions.